# Can Jx in one command with vim?

Tags: vim

J command transform two lines like

```
foo
bar
```

in

```
foo bar
```

It is possibile to transform

```
foo
bar
```

in

```
foobar
```

without "Jx"? There are other ways to Jx lines?

Answer (score 4):

`gJ` will join lines without making new space.

```
                            *gJ*
gJ          Join [count] lines, with a minimum of two lines.
            Don't insert or remove any spaces.  {not in Vi}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid insertion of any extra spaces between the joined lines, use `:j!` (`:join!`) command (see `:help :join`) instead of <kbd>J</kbd>.

For example, <kbd>J</kbd> can be remapped to `:j!` with the following command:

```
:nnoremap J :j!<CR>
```